# Will Ubuntu installation process be straight forward on any laptop?

Tags: system-installation

So I'm getting a new laptop and I'm considering Ubuntu as my OS. Ive just recently started to famarilize myself with Linux in a uni class, but I understand that it would suit my education well.

Now to my question. If I were to buy a new laptop, (considering the Huawei Matebook X pro, or a any other laptop with Windows installed from the get go. New/pre-owned) is there anything I need to be aware of. I read the installation guide on the Ubuntu website and it seems quite simple, but read some articles that had me worried, talking about performance issues, battery life decreases and so on?

Thank for answers!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This question is a bit too broad to receive an answer and would likely receive opinions more than anything. That said, Ubuntu does install quite easily on just about any modern x86-based machine (some ARM devices require a bunch of extra work). There are occasionally issues with hardware that was specifically designed for Windows (or macOS), but you'll find the vast majority of notebooks will work reasonably well with a stock installation. As with any investment, do your research beforehand to avoid disappointment, which you seem to be doing 

Comment: This is not really a question we can answer here. We can't really solve hypothetical problems. We also can not help with hardware shopping recommendations. Installing Ubuntu is straightforward and we have an [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). As a new Linux user I would encourage you *not* to base your information from articles and blog posts. Like anything else on the internet, you can get into trouble if you rely on sources that are not knowledgeable or authoritative.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I will remember that for upcoming questions!  And thanks for the advise!

Comment: Do you want to keep Windows and install Ubuntu in a dual boot setup? Or do you want to nuke Windows and go Ubuntu by itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

1. When in doubt, purchase from a vendor with a generous return policy.
2. The Ubuntu installer has a "Try Ubuntu" environment so you can test your hardware BEFORE installing. Use it.

   Test, test, test BEFORE installing. Test your video, your audio, the camera, the microphone. Test playing a movie. Test your internet connection, your wireless, your bluetooth. Test all your peripherals, including printers, phones, and external drives.

   Make sure it all works before committing to an install. You are investing an afternoon for surety.
3. Now you are ready to carefully install Ubuntu

Comment: Some laptops have Bitlocker enabled by default in Windows. If you don't disable it in Windows, the Ubuntu installation may fail and leave Windows in an unbootable state.